# Is there a bash equivalent to "some content #{foo}" with ruby?

Tags: bash, ruby

I'm used to being able to pass variables inside strings in ruby, like so

```
"message in double quotes #{expression_or_variable_to_run}"
```

What's the equivalent in bash, for really quick scripting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Source hostname from command.
echo "Hostname is $(hostname)"

# Set hostname as string.
HOSTNAME="somestring"
echo "Hostname is ${HOSTNAME}"
```

Comment: Beat me by that much.

Comment: However, $() is not "sourcing" - it's a subshell.

Comment: Ah, this is -exactly- what need, thanks!

Comment: I didn't mean source in a Bash '. ' sense. Just that the command was the source of the string. Semantics ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you understand some basics:

```
#!/bin/bash
VARIABLE="is"
echo "the server $VARIABLE `hostname`"
```

Variables are defined without $, referenced with $. Shell commands can be executed within `` quotes.

Comment: backticks should be extracted with a hot needle and a pair of tweezers - **use $() instead** - http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082